# Java: File locked?

Tags: java, java-io

I have written a programm the copies files. For each file there is a thread, that handels the copy process. After the file is copied, i want to delete the file, but the file is locked. I have closed the inputstream and also the outputstream of the file, after the process is done. Any ideas why i cant delete the files, even after both streams were closed? The project is pretty big, for this reason i can't post the whole code here.

This is the part where the file get copied:

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    outputStream.flush();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(inputStream != null) {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(outputStream != null) {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? Anyway do not re-invent the wheel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927203/java-copy-file-to-either-new-file-or-existing-file

Comment: Just because you can copy it with your java program does not mean that the java program is what is locking the file. Maybe something else on your computer has a lock on that file?

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: If you're not using a super-old version of Java (Java 7 or newer), then you can copy files with one line: `Files.copy(...)` - much easier than this manual copying process.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Windows 8.1

Comment: @Jesper There is a reason, why i copy the files like this, but i can't get deeper into why in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that your input stream is not opened within the `try{}/finally{}` block in which it is closed. Because of that, if an error occurs in your InputStream, the file will only get closed if that error happens inside the block you show above.

A second possible cause is that you close two things within the same `finally` block. Since `close()` throws `IOException`, if an exception occurred closing the first file, the second file would not get closed. You may want to consider allocating all of your closeable resources using the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax, which will take care of closing files for you and eliminate the possibility of one exception keeping another file from closing properly.  For example,

```
try(InputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile); OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    ... your logic goes here
}
```

You can add a `catch` if you want to, but you no longer need `finally` since your files will be closed for you, even if exceptions are thrown.

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you do not have sufficient permissions to create the file via FileOutputStream.

Just tested your code on my machine and it worked with proper write permissions.